# SharePoint search service vs list service to retrieve documents from a document library

Tags: sharepoint

We have a requirement to retrieve document details from a sharepoint document library. We understand that we can use either list web service or search web service. Can any one please let us know which is better? Is list web service faster than search web service?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Go for the list Web service when you only need to retrieve documents from a single document library. The search Web service cannot return all document properties (e.g. list item id, checked out status, and more) and there is also a lag from document changes till the search crawler visits the document library and updates the search index.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion. Just had few more questions. Do you know if list service is faster than search service? Also, would like to know why any one would use search services instead of list services? Is search service better option only in those cases where there is a need to search across multiple document libraries or is there any other benefit?

Comment: Not sure which one is faster - but my guess is the lists service. Yes, I would mostly recommend the search service in the cases where you need to search across multiple libraries on multiple sites. Searching multiple libraries on a single site or a few sites can also be achieved with good efficiency using the SPSiteDataQuery class. The need to search keywords inside documents is another reason to use the search service. The lists service cannot do this.